# Do I need to apply for a visa for a one-week tour to Indonesia?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, indonesia

I want to go to Indonesia, so I booked a round-trip ticket with CheapOAir.

Travel: one week

Purpose: tourism

Citizenship: USA

I was sure I didn't need a visa to Indonesia since I have a US passport. However when I booked the ticket CheapOAir prompted me to buy a visa for $70.

I tried calling them but only got a vague answer. It's called a CIBT visa. I'm confused. Do I need to apply for a visa? Or can I get one when I arrive?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

CIBT is not a visa; it's a company that provides visa services.

US citizens (and citizens from most countries in fact) can [enter Indonesia visa free](https://consular.embassyofindonesia.org/page/visafree.html) for up to 30 days for tourism and certain other purposes if you meet the requirements. That period cannot be extended. There's also [a $35 visa-on-arrival](https://consular.embassyofindonesia.org/page/visaonarrival.html) for 30 days, which can be extended once. You can also [review the visa information provided by the US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/Indonesia.html). And [according to Timatic](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC), the database used by airlines for visa information:

> The following are exempt from holding a visa:
>
> Nationals of USA for a maximum stay of 30 days.
>
> This does not apply when traveling for journalism visits.
>
> Visa issuance:
>
> Nationals of USA can obtain a visa on arrival for a maximum stay of 30
>   days if their passport contains at least half an unused visa page and
>   if they have at least USD 1,000.- or a valid credit card. They can
>   apply to extend their stay for an additional 30 days.
>
> Passengers can apply for a visa on arrival at Balikpapan (BPN), Banda
>   Aceh (BTJ), Bandung (BDO), Batam (BTH), Denpasar-Bali (DPS), Jakarta
>   (Halim Perdana Kusuma (HLP) and Soekarno-Hatta (CGK), Kupang (KOE),
>   Lombok (LOP), Medan Kuala Namu (KNO), Makassar (UPG), Manado (MDC),
>   Padang (PDG), Palembang (PLM), Pekan Baru (PKU), Pontianak (PNK),
>   Semarang (SRG), Surabaya (SUB), Surakarta (Solo) (SOC) or Yogyakarta
>   (JOG).
>
> Additional information:
>
> Passengers exceeding their permitted stay will be fined (Note: The day
>   of arrival in Indonesia is counted as the first day of stay).

If you are staying for a purpose that requires a visa or staying longer than the visa free period, you'll need to obtain a visa in advance. You can use a service like CIBT to assist in that process, or apply for one yourself through the Indonesian Consulate.